# Как прервать проигрыш звука другим звуком при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: c#, unity3d, аудио

Делаю програму, где есть много кнопок, и при нажатии на каждую производиться какая-то цитата звуком.

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на другую кнопку, звук, который играл от предыдущей прерывался и начинал играть другой.

На всех кнопках висит этот скрипт:

```
AudioSource _audio;

private void Start()
{
    _audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

public void PlayAudio()
{
    _audio.Play();
}
```

На данный момент звуки с разных кнопок стакаются и получается "каша".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как это сделать в обычном дотнете, знаю, а как грамотно реализовать в Unity - к сожалению не спец, но попробую подсказать в общих чертах.

По идее нужен еще один объект, который будет запускать звук и сохранять у себя в поле запущеный `AudioSource`. При запуске следующего стопать предыдущий и запускать следующий, что-то типа этого.

```
private AudioSource _currentAudio;

public void PlaySolo(AudioSource audio)
{
    _currentAudio?.Stop();
    _currentAudio = audio;
    _currentAudio.Play();
}

public void Stop()
{
    _currentAudio?.Stop();
    _currentAudio = null;
}
```

То есть это должен быть отдельный скрипт, к экземпляру которого должен быть доступ у всех ваших скриптов, которые хотят воспроизводить аудио.

Вызов выглядеть будет примерно так

```
public void PlayAudio()
{
    _player.PlaySolo(_audio);
}
```

На гениальость не претендую, Unity не знаю, это просто очевидное для меня с логической точки зрения решение.